# Personality quiz in wordpress using a plugin

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, plugin-recommendation

I am trying to create a personality quiz in WordPress using a plugin 'quiz and survey master'. The plugin gives the ability to assign points to each answer but, the problem is , my quiz is based on categories and each category has some questions and the end result of the quiz is determined based on points scored in each category. e.g in category 'a' user scores 'x' points and his result will be 'xyz'(same in each category). The problem with this plugin is that i can calculate the total score of the quiz. Is there any other way or other plugin available that can do this task. Help will be really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked with the plugin developer?  There's always another way but what you're asking for seems like instructions on how to use a plugin or modify it, which is off-topic and hard to answer unless someone is intimately familiar with the plugin.  The alternative would be to build your own quiz utility.

Comment: I'm looking for a alternate plugin which can do the job.